# dompdf não exibe font georgia

Tags: php, css, dompdf

quero exibir um arquivo com a font-family Georgia, já baixei e coloquei na pasta fonts de sua lib, mas estou buscando e não exibe no formato Georgia.
Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês.

**style**

```
body{
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#555;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

**Como Exibe**
[image: no formato correto o 5.1 não estariam alinhados]

Se estivesse com a fonte Georgia, o 5.1 não estaria alinhado, correto?

Comment: No navegador exibe?

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar a fonte que vc está usando, posso testar aqui

Comment: Cara se vc quer referenciar uma fonte que está na pasta vc tem que usar o @font-face para indexar a fonte no documento e só então ela estará disponível no font-family... Como a Georgia é nativa no Windows, eu fiz um teste aqui e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: hugocsl eu até fiz isso, mas tava colocando todo o arquivo em negrito. @font-face {
       font-family: "Georgia";
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       font-variant: normal;
       src: url("'.$url.'/dompdf/lib/fonts/Georgia.ttf") format("truetype");
   }

Comment: Onde estiver em negrito coloca `font-weight: normal;` no CSS

Comment: @sam http://sistema.ferreiraeborzone.com.br/feb-homologacao/dompdf/lib/fonts/Georgia.ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, como eu resolvo isso, talvez te ajude

1) Procuro uma equivalente quando a fonte é paga, Georgia é registrada pela Microsoft, por exemplo, mas essa livre é bem parecida: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Neuton

2) Configuro ela e:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:400,700&display=swap');
body {
font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
}
</style>
```

Se ainda quiser resolver via Biblioteca, esse link pode ser útil: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1627

Comment: Poxa, eu tinha lido isso da fonte ser registrada pela microsoft, mas pensei que dava pra puxar pelo Dompdf.

Comment: Acho que até pode funcionar, mas aí você precisa ficar bem atento nas especificações da biblioteca e sempre dá problema... dá uma olhada nisso, talvez te ajude também: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1627 ; sempre preciso trabalhar com fontes personalizadas e procurar uma solução diferente para cada caso me fez resolver tudo com similares (quando cabível no projeto)

Comment: Adicionei esse link à resposta, pode ser útil; já que minha resposta cabe mais para pergunta sobre fontes personalizadas de forma geral. Boa sorte!

Comment: usei o seu exemplo Leonardo, mesmo assim não funcionou. Não sei aonde estou errando!